# Create element from its constructor (without knowing the element tag)

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element, native-web-component

Is it possible to create an element if you have its constructor but don't know its tag name?

Example:

```
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {}
customElements.define(genRandomString(), CustomElement);
```

Is it possible to create a new instance of `CustomElement`? Or can you obtain its tag name in any way?

I'm asking this because I'm not sure what's the correct way to pass custom elements to functions that need them: do I need to pass around both the name and the constructor, in case one may need to either create an element (which requires the name) or to check whether an existing element is of this kind (which requires the constructor)?

Comment: Why not just do `new CustomElement`?

Comment: Why not just add a static property 
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
public static tagName = "i-am-a-tag";
}

and then with this  tagName we can check if it exist or not

Comment: @Dreamweaver Sidenote: This is not a Typescript question, hence no `public`.

Comment: `new CustomElement()` was not working for me. I realized that I hadn't registered it with `customElements.define`. After registering it, it's now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to create an element if you have its constructor but don't know its tag name?

If you have access to the constructor (like you said you have), you can just use

```
const instance = new CustomElement();
```

Please note that this might fail if the `constructor` doesn't conform to [Custom Element constructor constraints](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance).

Comment: It didn't work because I hadn't registered the element with `customElements.define`.

After registering the element, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are asking for:

```js
let foo = "bar";
window[ genRandomString() ] = foo;
```

And then you want to know what `getRandomString` produced?

Only when you monitor `window` can you capture what is added to it.

Same with WebComponents, only when you *hook* into `customElements.define` can you record what names are used.
In other words: mess with its `prototype` and potentially breaking its default execution.

But this only works from the moment you are in control; you could have missed all Web Components created already, at that time.

Can you explain WHY you want to do this?